# how to Parse XML using XElement.Parse without looking/changing Entities to characters?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml, xelement

Is theres a way to Parse XML using XElement.Parse that won't convert entities to a character?

*example:*

```
var xmlText = "<name><firstname>Willi&aacute;ms</firstname></name>";
```

and if I Parse this using the below:

```
var element = XElement.Parse(xmlText);
var firstname = element.Element("firstname");
```

after parsing, `firstname` value is now "Williáms"

How can I ignore those entities to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character "&" is illegal in XML elements. "&" will generate an error because the parser interprets it as the start of an character entity.

To be corrective, your Xml should be using CDATA:

```
var xmlText = "<name><firstname><![CDATA[Willi&aacute;ms]]></firstname></name>";
```

Comment: How can I check this if I'm reading those tags in an input of XMLs?

Comment: @AllanRoyMalibiranBalderama: You don't check anything, your code works

Comment: but I'm planning to have a preview of XML using a XMLViewer. This process will hide entities...

Comment: I am not sure I understand you, could you elaborate in your question?

Comment: I'm creating a WPF program that will capture some xml tags from an XML to create another XML (which I'll treat as its metadata). After checking and validation, the user can update and Edit values in a preview of XML. If we will use this CDATA process, those entities will list be hidden with that.

Comment: I don't think it's true to say that 'Character "&" is illegal in XML elements'! In this case would &aacute; be valid if it was a defined entity?

Comment: Is there a way to do this for every possible entity in the entire XML string?